# Selecting values of a DataFrame using a separate DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` from which I'd like to select a unique value from each row based on a boolean criteria from a separate `DataFrame` with an identical index.    Below `a` is the `DataFrame` I want to pick one value
from:

```
In [1]: a
Out[1]: 
                            0         1         2
2015-05-22 15:00:00 -2.243827  0.791424 -0.213561
2015-05-22 15:00:10 -0.501101 -0.260765 -0.707294
2015-05-22 15:00:20  0.223438  0.448361  0.741621
2015-05-22 15:00:30 -2.361507  0.464903  0.913033
2015-05-22 15:00:40  0.400453 -1.860845 -1.018406
```

and `b` is the `DataFrame` I want to use to index things

```
In [2]: b
Out[2]: 
                         0      1      2
2015-05-22 15:00:00  False   True  False
2015-05-22 15:00:10  False  False   True
2015-05-22 15:00:20   True  False  False
2015-05-22 15:00:30   True  False  False
2015-05-22 15:00:40   True  False  False
```

the indexing is easy but the unselected values are all `NaN`s but I'd like to get rid of these and only leave the non-null values.

```
In [3]: d=a[b]
In [4]: d
Out[4]:
                            0         1         2
2015-05-22 15:00:00       NaN  0.791424       NaN
2015-05-22 15:00:10       NaN       NaN -0.707294
2015-05-22 15:00:20  0.223438       NaN       NaN
2015-05-22 15:00:30 -2.361507       NaN       NaN
2015-05-22 15:00:40  0.400453       NaN       NaN
```

My kluge solution is to convert all the `NaN`s to 0 and then sum each row

```
In [5]: d[np.isnan(d)]=0
In [6]: d
Out[6]: 
                            0         1         2
2015-05-22 15:00:00  0.000000  0.791424  0.000000
2015-05-22 15:00:10  0.000000  0.000000 -0.707294
2015-05-22 15:00:20  0.223438  0.000000  0.000000
2015-05-22 15:00:30 -2.361507  0.000000  0.000000
2015-05-22 15:00:40  0.400453  0.000000  0.000000

In [7]: e=d.sum(axis=1)
In [8]: e
Out[8]: 
2015-05-22 15:00:00    0.791424
2015-05-22 15:00:10   -0.707294
2015-05-22 15:00:20    0.223438
2015-05-22 15:00:30   -2.361507
2015-05-22 15:00:40    0.400453
Freq: 10S, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way I can do this with indexing.  I've tried multiple things and am not finding a good or better solution.

Comment: You don't need `d[np.isnan(d)]=0`, you can directly do `d.sum(axis=1)`, which comes down to single liner like `a[b].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: So the question really boils down to how one gets the index location of `True` columns in a given row.

Comment: I suspect the way you are doing it (as improved by @JohnGalt) is about as good a way as any since you are starting with a mask (the `b` dataframe).  Any other solution will involve something along the lines of converting `[False False True]` to `2` and then pluging that into `iloc`.  But I don't see any advantage to that over what you are already doing.  Now if you aren't actually starting with that mask, then there might be a better way.

Comment: @JohnGalt's method works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to stack the result:

```
d = a[b].stack()
```

The default setting will drop the null values. This will give you a second level in your index which may not want. Just drop it if not. Summing along axis=1 will only work if there is one `True` in each row which may not always be the case.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting you can do it with stack.  Seems fine although it's not obvious to me that it is any better or worse than `a[b].sum(axis=1)` as suggested above.

Comment: Yeah I just thought it might be helpful in the slightly different situation where there isn't exactly one ```True``` in each row. Also, I think the problem is essentially turning multiple columns into one, which I think naturally falls into the realm of pivot and stack etc. Summing across null values is somehow less intuitive to me. Also, it may be of interest to retain the information of which column the non-null value in each row came from. On the other hand, it would seem that stack is around 2-3 times slower